# Batch File to check Folder continuously for new CSV files , renaming them one after another and start Firefox with current File

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv

the Batch File should scan a certain folder continuously for new csv files and whenever a new csv-file is placed in the folder, the csv-file should be renamed to a specific filename, because a firefox extension shall read that file.

I have already written a batch file for this but I think the solution is not perfect.
This is my attempt:

I start with the batch-file InitRun.bat:

```
@echo off

for /L %%i in (1,1,86400) do (
call FFRun1.bat
timeout /T 1
)
```

FFRun1.bat looks like this:

```
@echo off

FOR %%f in (*Data.csv) do ( 
echo %%f
set FILE=%%f
call :copy
)
goto end

:copy
copy /y %FILE% merged.csv
del %FILE%
call :RunFF

:RunFF
type merged.csv
pushd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\"
start /wait firefox.exe
popd 

:end
exit /b
```

If I place two or more csv-files at the same in the Folder, my solution can only process one csv and merged.csv only contains the last processed csv. In addition Firefox opens several windows, but also only works with the last csv which was copied to merged.csv.

Each new csv-File has the filename *Data.csv and should be renamed to merged.csv and for each new csv-file, firefox should start in a new tab and process the current merged.csv.
The csv-Files should not be renamed all at once, but one after another. Also Firefox should not start multiple windows/instances at a time.

I hope you can help me.

Regards,

Kepler

Answer (score 0):

It should do what you indicate iterating over the directory in date order and converting the *data.csv into merge csv for later process (firefox changed with notepad for testing, adapt as neede). Also it will check if .csv files are in use, and wait for file to become available. If a file can not be processed (in use) no later file will be accesible until locked file become available (process files in generation order)

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "folder=d:\temp"
    set "files=*data.csv"

    pushd "%folder%"
    for /l %%a in (0 0 1) do (
        if exist "%files%" (
            echo files found
            set "done="
            for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /od "%files%"') do if not defined done (
                call :replace "merged.csv" "%%d"
                if not errorlevel 1 (
                    start "" /wait notepad "merged.csv"
                ) else (
                    set "done=1"
                )
            )
        ) else (
            echo no files to process
        )
        timeout.exe /t 2 >nul 
    )

    endlocal
    exit /b

:replace target source
    if exist "%~1" del /f /q "%~1" >nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo file "%~1" is in use
        exit /b 1
    )
    ren "%~2" "%~1" >nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo file "%~2" is in use
        exit /b 1
    )
    exit /b 0
```